# Excel VBA Autofilter Compile Error: Expected: expression

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to filter a sheet by the name "RA" appearing in the second column. I've constructed the following code but it seems there is a compile error: Expected: Expression after I click enter on the line "Field:= ....". Is this the correct syntax for what I am trying to achieve? Thanks.

```
With CurrentSheet
    Set LastAddressCurrent = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    LastRowCurrent = LastAddressCurrent.Row
    .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(LastAddressCurrent, LastRowCurrent)).AutoFilter
        Field:= 2, Criteria1:= "RA"
    End If
End With
```

Comment: `.Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(LastAddressCurrent, LastRowCurrent)).AutoFilter Field:= 2, Criteria1:= "RA"` this should come in a single line.

Comment: or write `....)).AutoFilter _` and then in next line write `Field:= 2, Criteria1:= "RA"`

Comment: Also, there is `End If` but I don't see `If`...

Comment: Yeah that wasn't meant to be there. I previously had an if statement but it deleted it. It works now. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a code line continuation `_`